# Comparing 2 elements of a 3x3 matrix to see if element 2 is adjacent to element 1

Tags: algorithm, validation, matrix, selection

Basically, I'm creating a puzzle where you can swap pieces. And I want to make sure that when swapping 2 elements, the selection is valid.

Since the puzzle is only 9 pieces (3x3), I am currently using the code:

```
  function valid_selection(p1, p2) {
   if (p1 == 1 && (p2 == 2 || p2 == 4)) return true;
   if (p1 == 2 && (p2 == 1 || p2 == 3 || p2 == 5)) return true;
   if (p1 == 3 && (p2 == 2 || p2 == 6)) return true;
   if (p1 == 4 && (p2 == 1 || p2 == 5 || p2 == 7)) return true;
   if (p1 == 5 && (p2 == 2 || p2 == 4 || p2 == 6 || p2 == 8)) return true;
   if (p1 == 6 && (p2 == 3 || p2 == 5 || p2 == 9)) return true;
   if (p1 == 7 && (p2 == 4 || p2 == 8)) return true;
   if (p1 == 8 && (p2 == 5 || p2 == 7 || p2 == 9)) return true;
   if (p1 == 9 && (p2 == 6 || p2 == 8)) return true;

   return false;
  }
```

But, can I do this programatically? Anyone know of such an algorithm?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please describe the check sequence, because we do not know the rules of the game.

Comment: You can easily see that by studying my current code. It's kinda hard to explain,

Comment: Yeah sorry for the ambiguity, technically it is. But in the future I may want to go from a 3x3 matrix to, say, 4x4, and then I would have to hard-code 16 possibilities, and I'm sure you agree that this doesn't scale well when I increase it to a 100*100 matrix, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your matrix has positions like so:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

You should be able to do the following:

```
if ( abs(p2-p1) == 3 // test for vertical connectedness
        || ( abs(p2-p1) == 1 // test for horizontal connectedness
        && ( p1+p2 != 7 && p1+p2 != 13) ) ) // except for edge cases (3,4 and 6,7)
    return true;
```

Comment: That's exactly how my matrix is, and it doesn't work properly.

Example:

let p1=4
and p2=3

It shouldn't match as p2 is in the top right corner (p1 is in the middle left), but it passes the if test.

Comment: Nope, this fails on p1=2, p2=5 when it should match,
Also fails on: p1=5,p2=8

Comment: I don't know why it would fail, if you look at the code - clearly it will return true on 2,5 and 5,8. Check to make sure your braces are correct.

Comment: Oops, my bad. It does work indeed. Just one more question, what is so special about 7 and 13, and how did you derive that? Cheers for your help.

Comment: Horizontal connectedness is if p1 and p2 are 1 apart, except for in positions (3,4) and (6,7). So you can add p1+p2 to check if they are in these positions - and you exclude them. There is a more general approach (You can use the width of the matrix to find these instead) but this is small enough that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert each piece on the grid into coordinate form.

ie:

1 is (0,0),
2 is (0,1),
3 is (0,2),
4 is (1,0),
etc

So, given that the coordinate of p1 is (x_p1, y_p1) and p2 is (x_p2, y_p2) then your function would return true if:

( abs(x_p2 - x_p1) + abs(y_p2 - y_p1) ) == 1

I think...? Haven't actually tried it.

And this should work regardless of grid size.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is JavaScript:

```
var N = 3;  // size of matrix

var x1 = p1 % N, y1 = Math.floor(p1 / N);
var x2 = p2 % N, y2 = Math.floor(p2 / N);

return (x1 == x2 && Math.abs(y2 - y1) == 1) ||
       (y1 == y2 && Math.abs(x2 - x1) == 1);
```